# Keyboard keys count records

Tags: keyboard

Standard keyboards have ~100 and something keys. Some keyboards have additional buttons, like media controls, custom buttons, etc. However, most of those still have similar layouts and still the number of keys is similar, i.e maybe in ~110 range or so.

I was wondering are there keyboards with significantly more keys than that, e.g. 140 or more. Or to phrase this better - what's the keyboard that has the highest number of keys? I'm mostly interested in keyboards you can buy, not experimental models, but I'd be glad to hear about those too, especially if they are not "just for fun" but actually useful.

I'm mostly interested in not using mouse and instead use keyboards with more keys to compensate, so I'm coming from the typing comfort / speed perspective here.

Also not limited to "usual keyboards". For example, [chorded keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorded_keyboard) are interesting in a way that although they do not have many keys, each chord can be thought of as a key.

Comment: Does [this](http://allswellworld.blogspot.nl/2011/02/worlds-biggest-keyboard.html) count ;)

Comment: You question does not make sense. You will not compensate for absense of mouse with more keys. You will not get better typing comfort from haveing 140+ keys on your keyboard. What is it that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidPostill :)) Wonderful! Now if we can have a few dozen people typing, we'd have a new concept of *crowd-typing*!

Comment: @smc To clarify - I did not want to say not using the mouse *at all*, just using it less, given the availability of more keys to compensate for some mouse functions. Think Vim or Emacs.

Comment: A regular keyboard can produce massive amount of different input combinations If you consider all possible modifier keys. Do you still need more? What is your exact requirement?

Comment: @smc I think I explained that well - *comfort / speed*. A keyboard with one Ctrl key and 3 regular keys can produce 6 combinations, but I'd rather have a keyboard with 6 keys - it's faster and my wrists will thank me. Also, convenient modifier+key combinations are often "stolen" by OS. So requirements are hopefully clear as per the questions - more keys. The other requirement - that it's in production / non-experimental - hopefully would weed out the things like 22k key keyboard that David posted. Though I'm all ears, as a person can always learn something new every day.